# Rails 3. has_many as another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have two models: User and ScheduledSession

The users have roles. One of the roles is "instructor".

```
ScheduledSession
belongs_to :instructor, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'instructor_id'

User
has_many :scheduled_sessions
```

GOOD! So I can do this...

```
s = ScheduledSession.first
s.instructor
```

BAD! But I can't do this...

```
u = User.first
u.scheduled_sessions
```

I get this error...

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: scheduled_sessions.user_id: SELECT "scheduled_sessions".* FROM "scheduled_sessions"  WHERE "scheduled_sessions"."user_id" = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: scheduled_sessions.user_id: SELECT "scheduled_sessions".* FROM "scheduled_sessions"  WHERE "scheduled_sessions"."user_id" = 1
```

How can I setup the relationship the other way around so I can see which scheduled sessions belongs to that instructor (user)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set the foreign key in the User has_many relationship as well.

```
has_many :scheduled_sessions, :foreign_key => 'instructor_id'
```

Comment: so simple, awesome! thanks. (it just needs a comma right before :foreign_key)

Comment: I fixed it in case someone else came across.